# After updating my angular 2 to version 2.1.1

Tags: angular, angular2-material

After updating my angular 2 to version 2.1.1 I get this error:

> node_modules/@angular2-material/core/gestures/MdGestureConfig.d.ts(4,40):
>   error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HammerManager'

when I try to run `npm start`. I guess this is due to the typings that was taken out. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Due to the removal of typings from angular2 version 2.1.1, I installed 
@types/hammerjs. I used the following command:

**npm i --save-dev @types/hammerjs**
This solved my problem. Thanks to https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/1049.